# Creating a new partition in empty space between 2 existing ext4 partitions

Tags: linux, partition

Output of `fdisk -l`:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 640.1 GB, 640135028736 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 77825 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x07f2837e

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1               1          13      104391   de  Dell Utility
/dev/sda2   *          14        1926    15360000    7  HPFS/NTFS
/dev/sda3            1926       27578   206055449+   7  HPFS/NTFS
/dev/sda4           27579       77826   403610625    5  Extended
/dev/sda5           27579       52921   203561523+  83  Linux
/dev/sda6           59000       59972     7811072   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda7           59972       77826   143407104   83  Linux
```

A few things to note:

1) There's around 50GB of unallocated space betweed sda5 and sda6.

2) sda5 is mounted at `/` on my Ubuntu install, and sda7 is mounted at `/home`.

I want to install Fedora in the unallocated space by creating a 50GB ext4 partition. I would create only a single root partition in that space without modifying any partition around, and I'll take care of all the GRUB mess.

My question is: Will creating an ext4 partition between sda5 and sda6 change the sdaX numbering of the swap and /home partitions? I guess yes. In any case, will it also change the UUID of any other partition? I'm asking this because I can see in my ubuntu fstab that the partitions are identified by their UUID. If I just create a partition in the unallocated space and install Fedora, will the UUIDs change of the surrounding drives so much that the drives won't auto-mount at Ubuntu startup?

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: At the next disk-partitioning crossroads, consider using [LVM](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/LVM-HOWTO/), so you don't have to worry about things like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. It will not change the partitioning number of said device. And you can create the new partition in between 5 and 6, and that partition will be sda8. UUID *will* remain same, as you are not modifying that partition.

Comment: Thanks. It all went smoothly for me. The UUID of sda{5,6,7} didn't change, and the new partition was named sda8, just like you had said.